# How to trigger a KeyboardEvent in Dart

Tags: dart

Like I said in the title, I would like to simulate a keyup event in Dart. The problem is that I have not found how create a new KeyboardEvent object.

The only way that I've found is to use the Event(String type) constructor and then dispatch it on window object. But that doesn't work because of my "keyup" handler who takes a KeyboardEvent in parameter. Example:

```
window.on.keyUp.add((KeyboardEvent e){
 print('keyUp handler');
});
KeyboardEvent e = new Event("KeyboardEvent");
window.on.keyUp.dispatch(e);
```

Is there a way to create and dispatch a KeyBoardEvent to simulate a "keyup" in Dart?

Also, I should mention that I tried too to trigger the event in JavaScript, thanks to js-interop library, but it only fires the JS handlers.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```dart
window.on.keyUp.add((Event event){
    print('keyUp handler');

    if(event is KeyboardEvent)
    {
      KeyboardEvent keyEvent = event as KeyboardEvent;
      //do stuff with keyEvent if needed
    }  
});

window.on.keyUp.dispatch(new Event("keyup"));
```

I think the parameter on the Event constructor must be the type of the event. Also, you can check if the event is a keyboardEvent, so you can handle KeyIdentifier, for example.

Comment: This solution works, but it can't be used for two reasons:
- The first is i must remove the typing
- The second is that if you want retreive the keyCode property of event in your handler (the case which happen all time ...) it's impossible simply because it not a KeyboardEvent

Comment: @mbreton Please, consider this new version of code, does it suit your needs?

Comment: Thank you Eduardo, but this should never work while we fire the window.on.keyUp with en event of type Event.
I need to trigger and KeyboardEvent for a unit test, so I need dispatch a KeyboardEvent with its properties properly initialized (I think at keyCode value mainly)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible now to Dispatch a KeyBoardEvent from window, please see discussion on Google Group for more information: https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/topic/misc/mgnd1TUGn68/discussion

Comment: Have you succeeded ? I tried the following without any success :    input.onKeyPress.listen((KeyboardEvent e) {
      if(e.keyCode == html.KeyCode.ENTER) {
        html.window.dispatchEvent(new html.KeyboardEvent("keypress", keyLocation: html.KeyCode.DOWN));
      }
    });